# JavaScript modulus not incrementing variable value correctly

Tags: javascript, variables, modulus

Could someone lend some advice here. I've written this script that is supposed to display max connections and current connections. When you add an additional connection, the maxDevice variable will get an additional 3, so if 3 out of 3 connections have been used, the next connection, 4 out of 3 would instead be displayed as 4 out of 6. Should the user reach 6 out of 6 and then go to 7 out of 6, the output would then change to 7 out of 9, as the max connection would again have 3 added to it, and continue on till infinity.

Using Modulus to find out if the device connection and max connection results in 0 is a good start however I'm not quite able to get the script to work above 6 as now if run, it will report 7 out of 12 which is obviously not what I am after.

I do not understand why the sudden jump from 3, 6 and now 12. Shouldn't it be 3, 6, 9?

Thanks for your time!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>You have used <span class="deviceNum"></span> out of <span class="maxcon"></span> available connections.</p>
<span class="devicenumwarning"></span>
</body>
<script>

var maxDevice = 3;
var deviceNum = 7;

if(deviceNum > maxDevice) {

    //check if device number is greater than max checkon from bap and warn user of upcharge
    $('.devicenumwarning').text('You have reached your connection rate.');


    for (i = 0; i < deviceNum; i++) { 

        console.log('this is: ' + maxDevice);
        if(i % maxDevice  === 0){ 
            maxDevice = parseFloat(maxDevice) + parseFloat(maxDevice);
        } 

        $('.deviceNum').text(deviceNum);
        $('.maxcon').text(maxDevice);

    }
maxDevice++;

} else {
    console.log('else');
    $('.maxcon').text(maxDevice);
    $('.deviceNum').text(deviceNum);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: why not just `maxDevice += 3`? and then remove `maxDevice++`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doubling maxdevice:

```
maxDevice = parseFloat(maxDevice) + parseFloat(maxDevice);
```

You should be adding 3 instead:

```
maxDevice = parseFloat(maxDevice) + 3;
```